# Send FCM Push notification to device within specific radius

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to to send push notification manually to devices around a specific location. I don't want to send a notification every time the device enters the radius, just once.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a message to devices that enter a specific area for the first time. That sort of specific requirement is up to you to build, on top of FCM and other APIs.

You'll need to have a background process that checks the user's location. Once you have that, you can send it to FCM. But also consider why you need FCM here in the first place, as you could also show a local notification in that case when the user first enters the area.